# Running blocks on the same thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, asynchronous, objective-c-blocks

I am running into a bit of an issue that I can't figure out. If I have a method signature with a Block parameter with a callback in it, and within my method I use a API that has another Block, the API executes `async` and my code continues on and invokes my callback method. This lets my view controller know that everything is completed, when in fact often times it's not due to the API block.

Since my method always invokes the callback method (and is ran async) can I force the API call that uses a block to run `synchronously`?

**View Controller**

```
[self.tagRepo sync:^(BOOL finished) {
    if (finished) {
        NSLog(@"Sync completed.");
        if (self.tagRepo.isSyncing)
            NSLog(@"Syncing continues...");
    }
}];
```

**[tagRepo Sync]**

```
- (void)sync:(void(^)(BOOL finished))completed {
    if (self.isSyncing)
        return;

    NSLog(@"Synchronizing tags...");
    self.isSyncing = YES;

    [[EvernoteNoteStore noteStore] getSyncStateWithSuccess:^(EDAMSyncState *syncState) {
        BOOL performCallback = YES;

        if (syncState.fullSyncBefore > lastSyncTime) {
            [self processSync:syncState];
        } else if (syncState.updateCount > self.lastUpdateCount) {
            [self processSync:syncState];
        } else {
            performCallback = NO; // Block calling the call back when we begin the listTagsWithSuccess async.
            self.clientTags = [[self fetchAll] mutableCopy];
            [[EvernoteNoteStore noteStore] listTagsWithSuccess:^(NSArray *tags) {
                self.serverTags = [tags mutableCopy];
                [self processClientTags]; // Only need to make sure client sends any new tags to the server.

                // invoke call back.
                self.isSyncing = NO;
                if (completed)
                    completed(YES);
            } failure:^(NSError *error) {
                self.isSyncing = NO;
                NSLog(@"Failed to list tags.");
            }];
        }

        self.isSyncing = NO;
        if (completed && performCallback)
            completed(YES);
    } failure:^(NSError *error) {
        self.isSyncing = NO;
        NSLog(@"Failed to process a sync.");

        if (completed)
            completed(NO);
    }];
}
```

What happens is that when I invoke the `[sync]` method, my NSLog's show that the callback method is invoked before any of my `processSync` methods are completed. This I am assuming is because the `processSync` method invocations take place within another block, so the completion block on the current thread goes ahead and gets called.

Am I using blocks in a incorrect manor or is there a typical way of handling callback's that have nested blocks within it. Should I be trying to run the secondary blocks on the current thread through some GCD dispatches? Set up KVO? The issue I ran in to with trying KVO was that the number of blocks within the API (Evernote's) used during a `sync` process varies, depending on what changes took place. So it's hard to determine when the `NSNotificationCenter` posts happen, what stage the sync is in and if it is completed/needs to execute a callback or post another notification. I assume there is a standard approach to getting around this. Any tips would be appreciated!

Johnathon.

**Update 1**

The following code gets called when I invoke the `[[EvernoteNoteStore noteStore] ^listTagsWithSuccess] method.

```
- (void)getSyncStateWithSuccess:(void(^)(EDAMSyncState *syncState))success 
                        failure:(void(^)(NSError *error))failure
{
    [self invokeAsyncIdBlock:^id {
        return [[self currentNoteStore] getSyncState:[self authenticationToken]];
    } success:success failure:failure];
}

- (void)listTagsWithSuccess:(void(^)(NSArray *tags))success
                    failure:(void(^)(NSError *error))failure
{
     [self invokeAsyncIdBlock:^id {
        return [[self currentNoteStore] listTags:[self authenticationToken]];
    } success:success failure:failure];
}

- (void)invokeAsyncIdBlock:(id(^)())block
                   success:(void(^)(id))success
                   failure:(void(^)(NSError *error))failure
{
    dispatch_async(self.session.queue, ^(void) {
        id retVal = nil;
        @try {
            if (block) {
                retVal = block();
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                               ^{
                                   if (success) {
                                       success(retVal);
                                   }
                               });
            }
        }
        @catch (NSException *exception) {
            NSError *error = [self errorFromNSException:exception];
            [self processError:failure withError:error];
        }
    });
}
```

**Update 2**

I provide the processSync method to show what other async stuff is being used. Within the processSync method I make another Evernote SDK method invocation, and then it ends up invoking processTags. I omit the processServerTags because the code is large, but included processClientTags, which is essentially the same as what is littered all through the processServerTags. So essentially I have 3-4 nested Evernote SDK async blocks running.

```
- (void)processSync:(EDAMSyncState *)syncState {
    BOOL fullSync = NO;
    // If we have never updated, perform full sync.
    if (!self.lastUpdateCount)
        fullSync = YES;

    [[EvernoteNoteStore noteStore] getSyncChunkAfterUSN:self.currentChunkUSN maxEntries:200 fullSyncOnly:NO success:^(EDAMSyncChunk *syncChunk) {
        // Loop, re-grabbing the next chunk
        if (syncChunk.chunkHighUSN < syncChunk.updateCount) {
            // Cache the current sync chunk. Since only so much is handed to us
            // during this hand-shake, we cache and go get more.
            [self cacheSyncChunk:syncChunk];
            self.currentChunkUSN = syncChunk.chunkHighUSN;

            // Fetch more sync chunks.
            [self processSync:syncState];
        } else {
            // Retrieved the last sync chunk, cache it and begin processing.
            [self cacheSyncChunk:syncChunk];
            self.currentChunkUSN = syncChunk.chunkHighUSN;

            // Build list of server tags
            [self processTags];

            // Time stamp ourselves so we know when we last updated.
            self.lastSyncTime = [NSDate endateFromEDAMTimestamp:syncState.currentTime];
            self.lastUpdateCount = syncState.updateCount;
        }
    } failure:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to process full sync.");
    }];
}

- (void)processTags {

    // Process the tags found on the server first. We bring down any new tags from the server and cache them.
    // Handles any naming conflicts or duplicate conflicts that come up.
    self.clientTags = [[self fetchAll] mutableCopy];
    [self processServerTags];

    // Process client tags. We check if the client has tags that do not exist on the server and send them.
    [self processClientTags];

    // Delete any expunged tags that we still have cached.
    [self expungeTags];

    NSLog(@"Completed syncing tags.");
}

- (void)processClientTags {
    NSLog(@"Processing client tags - Ensuring server is current with client tags.");
    // Now we compare our local cache to the server, in the event new tags were created.
    // TODO: Test this.
    for (Tag *clientTag in self.clientTags) {
        // Predicate for comparing all client tags against server tags.
        // We compare GUID's and Names. Since we can't have duplicate's of either, we check.
        // It is possible that the client created a Tag (GUID #1) and created it on the server externally (GUID #2) but share the same name.
        // In this case, we have to rename them.
        NSPredicate *compareGuidPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"guid == %@", clientTag.guid];

        //Check if this note exists already on the server.
        if (![[self.serverTags filteredArrayUsingPredicate:compareGuidPredicate] count]) {
            // If not, we make sure it was never expunged.
            if ([self.expungedTags containsObject:clientTag.guid])
                continue;

            EDAMTag *serverTag = [[EDAMTag alloc] initWithGuid:nil name:clientTag.name parentGuid:nil updateSequenceNum:0];
            serverTag = [self convertManagedTag:clientTag toEvernoteTag:serverTag convertingOnlyChangedProperties:NO];

            // Check which is newer. If the server is newer, update the client, if the client is newer
            // do nothing. It will be handled later under the processClientTags method.
            [[EvernoteNoteStore noteStore] createTag:serverTag success:^(EDAMTag *tag) {
                NSLog(@"Created new %@ tag on the server.", serverTag.name);
                clientTag.guid = tag.guid;
                NSLog(@"Server GUID %@ assigned to Client GUID %@", tag.guid, clientTag.guid);
                [self saveAllChanges];
            } failure:^(NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"Failed to create the %@ tag.\n%@", clientTag.name, [error description]);
            }];
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"Client tag processing completed.");
}
```

After reading Rob's answer, it looks like I will need to do some re-architecting of the source which isn't that big of an issue for me. For every method that has asynchronous code ran within it, the method signature will need to include a callback block. The async code will invoke that callback block when it is done.

Comment: Your code doesn't match your description of it. You are not doing _anything_ "async" in this code: you are never calling `dispatch_async()` or even `dispatch_sync()`. There is no "multithreading" going on here at all, and nothing "asynchronous". It would help if you showed _that_ part of your code, whatever and wherever it may be, since that is what you seem to be concerned with.

Comment: I updated my question to show the Evernote SDK async method that gets called for each Evernote method that includes a callback block.

Comment: So for clarification, just because code is ran within a block, does not mean it is passed onto another thread. So a block runs synchronous, unless the block is explicitly put onto another thread via GCD?

Comment: @JohnathonSullinger Blocks are just C functions. They do not run on different threads by default. Unless the Evernote API calls your blocks on different threads, you should assume they will be called on the main thread. Two blocks cannot execute concurrently on the same thread.

Comment: @LeoNatan unfortunately the Evernote SDK does run their blocks asynchronously. I updated my post to show their use of it. So each time I invoke one of their SDK methods, the method runs async. Creates a headache for me, as I can't determine when the processes complete in order to invoke my call back properly.

Comment: A block is just a functional syntactical construct, like a method or a function. THAT IS ALL. It happens that, for good reasons, blocks are *used* heavily by GCD. But blocks themselves are not about threads at all.

Comment: @JohnathonSullinger It sounds to me like you must understand threads. "I can't determine when the processes complete." No, that's not what you do when threads are involved. You do not "wait". You let their process call you (moving onto the main thread, typically).

Comment: @JohnathonSullinger To make sure, just put a breakpoint inside one of your blocks. Now see in Xcode on which thread it was called.

Comment: For example, a web view does its work asynchronously. But this does not pose any challenge for your code, because you get a delegate call when the web view has finished loading. - It might help you to read the Threading chapter of my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch38.html

Comment: So in my view controller, when I am within my callback block, it's common practice to return successful even if async calls running throughout the models are not done? If I get my callback and stuff is still running by 3rd parties, how do I determine if errors occurred?

Comment: No, in a proper architecture you get a callback on successful completion and you get a callback on error. You don't get anything if "calls running throughout the models are not done". The callback means everything _is_ done. (Of course the architecture might also provide a repeated message to let you know about the progress, but if you get that one, you know it's the progress message, not the completion message.)

Comment: It might also help you to read over this code I wrote: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch24p842downloader/ch37p1099downloader/MyDownloader.m That is very typical architecture. It is a class that takes a URL and a block from the caller, downloads that URL (an image) on a background thread, and then calls back the block (on the main thread).

Comment: Thanks, that's more or less what I was trying to get a answer on. How to handle callbacks as they bubble up from multiple async methods (can be nested 2-3 deep) to the original method invoked by the View Controller. How to keep track of what is running still and what has not completed.

Comment: Rob's answer was able to solve my issues. Moving my completion handler callback into the first async Evernote SDK block, and then wrapping each method call that I know performs another Evernote SDK async block within another completion block.

Comment: @JohnathonSullinger I read the chat discussion you had with Rob. It was great! Good work from both of you. - I still think you should read my Threading chapter, as it will help you get started with NSOperation.

Comment: Also do read Apple's [Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH1-SW1) as there are a lot of interesting ways to solve the sort of problem you're describing.

Comment: Thanks @matt I plan on taking a look at it. I need to read apples concurrency docs so my use of core data is done right. The async stuff is throwing a wrench in my use of the `NSManagedObjectContext`. Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're seeing your block you passed to `sync` called before the `processSync` methods are done, then that would suggest that `processSync` is, itself, must be performing some asynchronous operation. (You've updated your question with that code, and this appears to be the case.) If this is, in fact, the case, then you'd want to (a) change the `processSync` method to take a completion block parameter itself, and (b) have the `sync` method move the call to its own `completed()` to the block you pass to `processSync`. This way, you ensure that `completed()` is not called until it's really completed.

Thus, it might look something like:

```
- (void)sync:(void(^)(BOOL finished))completed {
    if (self.isSyncing)
        return;

    NSLog(@"Synchronizing tags...");
    self.isSyncing = YES;

    [[EvernoteNoteStore noteStore] getSyncStateWithSuccess:^(EDAMSyncState *syncState) {
        if (syncState.fullSyncBefore > lastSyncTime || syncState.updateCount > self.lastUpdateCount) {
            [self processSync:syncState completionHandler:^(BOOL finished){
                self.isSyncing = NO;
                if (completed)
                    completed(finished);
            }];
        } else {
            self.clientTags = [[self fetchAll] mutableCopy];
            [[EvernoteNoteStore noteStore] listTagsWithSuccess:^(NSArray *tags) {
                self.serverTags = [tags mutableCopy];
                [self processClientTags]; // Only need to make sure client sends any new tags to the server.

                // invoke call back.
                self.isSyncing = NO;
                if (completed)
                    completed(YES);
            } failure:^(NSError *error) {
                self.isSyncing = NO;
                NSLog(@"Failed to list tags.");
                if (completed)
                    completed(NO);
            }];
        }

        // self.isSyncing = NO;
        // if (completed && performCallback)
        //     completed(YES);
    } failure:^(NSError *error) {
        self.isSyncing = NO;
        NSLog(@"Failed to process a sync.");

        if (completed)
            completed(NO);
    }];
}
```

Note, this eliminates the `performCallback` boolean, as we simply ensure that all paths call the callback, and in the case of `processSync`, the calling of the callback is deferred until `processSync` has finished its asynchronous process first.

This obviously assumes that you will refactor `processSync` to take a completion handler of its own.

The bottom line is that you only want to call completion blocks when either (a) the ultimate asynchronous processes have successfully completed; or (b) have failed. But don't call the completion block until that asynchronous process is done, nesting it as necessary, as illustrated above.

Comment: I see you updated your question with `processSync`. Great. Every time you call a method that is, effectively asynchronous, add a completion block parameter. You can do this at each level.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I updated my original post to show the processSync method and a processClientTags method, which shows I end up with nested asynchronous Evernote SDK blocks. From looking at your answer, it looks like I need to re-architect my methods a little bit to bubble the completions up towards the originating method `sync`. This will help me out a lot. I appreciate it! As for the stylistic stuff, I am a bit new to the completion handler stuff so wasn't sure of the naming conventions. I agree my naming isn't the best. I will use your recommendations for that as well.

Comment: In the example of my processClientTags method, I use a for loop to go through a collection. Within that loop, I could potentially invoke another Evernote SDK async method. Within the evernote block, I don't want to invoke my processClientTag completion handler because I might not be finished with the for loop. At the end of the for loop, I would call my handler; what if the evernote async method isn't finished? I would need to know if it failed in the event of network connectivity failing, preventing the tag from being created on the server.

Comment: In this case, should I just queue up my tags within a mutable array and process outside of my loop, calling the handler within the async block when done? I could check if the queue is empty after each createTag call and then invoke my completion handler

Comment: @JohnathonSullinger You generally don't ever want to call your completion block until its actually completed. So don't call it until the final, most deeply nested Evernote process is done. If you _really_ need to pass back information about an update that is in progress (e.g. you want your UI to update a progress bar or something like that), you might have a second block, a "progress" block. But that's a level of complexity you might not want to tackle right now.

Comment: When I say completion block, I am referring to the one associated with the `processClientTags` method. So I call sync, which calls processTags, then `processClientTags`. Each ran async due to Evernote method invocations. So my `processClientTags` will have a completion handler to let `processTags` know it is done. I am asking what makes the most sense when `processClientTags` invokes async methods with callbacks within a for-loop?

Comment: @JohnathonSullinger By the way, you're currently returning a `BOOL` of whether its finished or not. A more common convention might be to return an `NSError` where `nil` means there was no error (and thus completed successfully) and something else would mean that it stopped due to an error, but more importantly, why it failed. When dealing with multiple levels like this, the original calling routine might want to know why it didn't succeed (e.g. no Internet connectivity, some authentication error, etc.). Without something like an `NSError` object, it will be hard to debug when you have issues.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46619/discussion-between-rob-and-johnathon-sullinger)